# "Automation error" after installing Windows 10 creators update

Tags: vb6

I've got a (old) third party application (written in vb6) which still worked great on Windows 10 (without creators update).

After the **Windows Creators Update** I get this error: **"Automation error"**

Windows debugger shows that it tries to load several Type Libraries.

Seems like any library is missing or wrong after the creators update.

The application developer won't help me. He tells, use an older OS.

Comment: Did you try to run it compatibility mode or use the compatibility trouble shooter?

Comment: This is not a Windows system DLL, so why would an OS update change it?  Wait... I see a copy in System32.  Who knew?

Comment: Hmm, seems like some 3rd party product installed this thing.

Comment: Compatibility mode whatever version, Admin mode ... everything already tried. Only using this older version of icuuc.dll solved the problem. That was the only problem here. (Even in Fall Creators Update)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause:** The library **icuuc.dll was replaced** by a newer version.

icuuc is a library for "International Components for Unicode". It's website is located here: http://icu-project.org/

The new version seems to be incompatible with the previous one (2003).

After copying the previous version dated 2003 (before creators update) next to the application exe (same folder) it uses this (old) version of icuuc.dll and the application works fine again.

Maybe this analysis result helps others with problems after the creators update, too.